# How to put each past commit on a separate branch of its own?

Tags: git-branch, git-commit, git

So I want to go from this state:

```
A - B - C - D - E
```

to this state:

```
A (feature/1 branch)
B (feature/2 branch)
C (feature/3 branch)
D (feature/4 branch)
E * master
```

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want to create new branches? Or do you also want to move each commit so they all have the same parent?

Comment: Is A the first revision in the history of the original branch? Then having feature/1 right there looks kind of funky because it would be part of the history of master (not that it's technically impossible, for sure.. just _funky_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `P` be the parent of `A`. As I understand, you want each of these commits to have `P` as its parent. For each commit, create a branch there, and then rebase it by "cutting" it off from its current parent and "pasting" it onto `P`:

```
git checkout -b feature/2 B
git rebase HEAD~1 --onto P

git checkout -b feature/3 C
git rebase HEAD~1 --onto P
```

and so on. `A` already has `P` as its parent, so you just need `git branch feature/1 A` to create the branch.